# split() after file.readines() giving an error

Tags: python

i am trying to use split() by reading using readlines(). My portion of the code is follows:

```
with contextlib.nested(open("inpfile","r"), open("numberAmpdus", "w")) as (inf, ouf):
    line = inf.readlines()
    ampdu = line.split()
```

Is this not the way to apply split after reading lines using readlines()? While running the program, i am getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Where should i change my code? I am using python2.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file.readlines()` returns a list of all lines, lists don't have any `split` method that's why you're getting that error.

```
lines = inf.readlines()
```

If you're trying to apply `str.split` to each item of `lines` then you have to iterate over this list and apply `str.split` to each item one by one.

```
ampdu = [x.split() for x in lines] # Applies `str.split` to each item of lines.
                                   # This create a new list, a list of lists
                                   # as `str.split` returns a list itself.
```

or :

```
for line in lines:
    ampdu = line.split()
    #now do something with `ampdu`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with contextlib.nested(open("inpfile","r"), open("numberAmpdus", "w")) as (inf, ouf):  
     lines = inf.readlines()   
         for line in lines:     
             ampdu = line.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

Python does not understand English: calling a variable `line` does not magically make it a line. In this case it is actually a *list* of lines, because that's what `readlines()` returns. You want to name your variable `lines` and iterate over it, or better yet, just iterate over the file itself, never reading the whole thing into memory.